# How to list files based on matching only part of their filename?

Tags: linux, command-line, globbing

I have many files in a folder for example

```
Kiran.txt
Kiran1.txt
Kiran221.txt
Kiran144.txt
Time.csv
Timer.csv
Timer2.csv
Timer444.csv
Timer266.csv
Account.sh
Account3.sh
Account3333.sh
Account3333.sh
Account333333.sh
```

From this directory, I want to know how I could use `grep` to display files based on part of their filename - for example those starting with "Account" or those ending in ".sh".

Comment: Thanks @DMA, I was just gonna do the same, you were a second faster. user663724, if you have similar questions, why not group them in one?

Comment: Nice edit, I thought I was looking at a different question at first, until I realised that the title and content had been modified to make the question more useful to a wider audience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `find`

```
find -type f -name "Account*"
```

Alternative 2 (this might include folder as well)

```
ls -1 Account*
```

Alternative 3 (grep, this could include folder as well)

```
ls -1 | grep -E "^Account"
```

Comment: I prefer `find` :-)

Answer (score 10):

Use a wildcard ([What is this wildcard?](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF)):

```
ls *.sh
```

The `*` will match anything before the ending `.sh` that you want. Use the other `ls` options for displaying, e.g. `-l` to make it a long listing. See `man ls` for more info about what you can do with it.

Note that `ls` would also list any *directory* ending with `.sh`, not only files.

---

You can also use `find` to overcome this problem.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.sh"
```

This command only lists "real" files. Using find is something I'd recommend if you want to do something with the found files afterwards. You can do this with [the `-exec` option](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find#Execute_an_action).

Comment: For OP: In addition, you can also use ? for a single charector as in "hel?o" to find "hello
" and "helwo"

Comment: I would put quotes around `*.sh` in the find command, as otherwise the shell would expand it to `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name Account.sh Account3.sh Account3333.sh Account333333.sh` in the question sample.

Comment: @BennyB Right, forgot them while copying. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The standard solution is a pipe:

```
ls | grep ^Account
```

With something as simple as "Files starting with Account", globs would also work:

```
ls Account*
```

but in general a grep is more powerful, and it doesn't run the risk of overflowing the maximum command line length if your folder is *really, really* full.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command

```
   ls *.sh
```