# How to list files ending with .sh only?

Tags: linux, command-line, globbing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use grep to see only Listed Files in a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/335160/how-to-use-grep-to-see-only-listed-files-in-a-directory)

I have many files in a folder, for example:

```
Kiran.txt
Kiran1.txt
Kiran221.txt
Kiran144.txt
Time.csv
Timer.csv
Timer2.csv
Timer444.csv
Timer266.csv
Account.sh
Account3.sh
Account3333.sh
Account3333.sh
Account333333.sh
```

From this directory, I want to only display the files ending with `.sh`. Please tell me how to do this.